# Query multiple properties in at the same time getting an overall average and an array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following data, I'm trying to get an average of all their ages, at the same time I want to return an array of their names. Ideally, I want to do this in just one query but can't seem to figure it out.

### Data:

```
users:[
 {user:{
  id: 1,
  name: “Bob”,
  age: 23
 }},
 {user:{
  id: 1,
  name: “Susan”,
  age: 32
 }},
 {user:{
  id: 2,
  name: “Jeff”,
  age: 45
 }
}]
```

### Query:

```
var dbmatch =  db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {"id" : 1}},
  {$group: {_id: null, avg_age: { $avg: "$age" }}},
  {$group: {_id : { name: "$name"}}}
)]
```

Running the above groups one at a time outputs the results I expect, either an _id of null and an average of 27.5, or an array of the names.

When I combine them as you see above using a comma, I get:

### Issue Generated Code:

```
[ { _id: {name: null } } ]
```

### Expected Generated Code:

```
[
  {name:"Bob"},
  {name:"Susan"},
   avg_age: 27.5
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is a link to the code with the error trying to both get an array and an average:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/3MMfp1e2JyA

You can delete either group and run it to see the correct result separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but this query

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$id",
            avg_age: {
                $avg: "$age"
            },
            names: {
                $push: {
                    name: "$name"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Results in this result:

```
[
  {
    "avg_age": 27.5,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "name": "Susan"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This will duplicate names, so if there are two documents with the name Bob, it will be two times in the array. If you don't want duplicates, change `$push` to `$addToSet`.

Also, if you want names to be just an array of names instead of objects, change names query to

```
  names: {
    $push: "$name"
  }
```

This will result in

```
[
  {
    "avg_age": 27.5,
    "names": ["Bob", "Susan"]
  }
]
```

Hope it helps,

Tomas :)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) [`aggregation`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EU2HrJZNZ5n) to run the multiple queries at once

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "firstQuery": [
      { "$match": { "id": 1 }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "avg_age": { "$avg": "$age" }
      }}
    ],
    "secondQuery": [
      { "$match": { "id": 1 }},
      { "$group": { "_id": "$name" }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony, ideally I wanted to do this in just one query and the answer I got from Tomas does just that.